# Configure: error: missing libstdc++ // UBUNTU UCK

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Right now I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware trying to make a Live CD with a tool called UCK. I am in the process where I can customize and add my own packages and tools to my live CD. I want to install and setup Autopsy so I began with the process of downloading both Sleuthkit and Autopsy. While trying to install those I have been told I have first have to use ./configure according to this guide: https://shankaraman.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/how-to-install-autopsy-and-sleuthkit-in-ubuntu/

and I got the following error: 'Configure: error: missing libstdc++'
Does anyone know how to fix this? I haven't found a solution on the internet yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by running: sudo apt-get install build-essential -_-.